# Does Googlebot simulate page scroll to load additional content?

Tags: seo, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, ajax, infinite-scroll

The content of the home page of the project I'm building is divided into 6 parts where the user scrolls and as soon as the first part "section" reaches the end another part is added via AJAX, but these parts only appear if the user scrolls.

I was wondering if Googlebot just reads the code the way it is to present it to the search engine, or do they have some sort of verification that simulates scrolling?

EX:

scroll in: -200

`Show <section>Hello 1</section>`

scroll in: -700

`Show <section>Hello 2</section>`

scroll in: -1400

`Show <section>Hello 3</section>`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be 100% certain the page will get properly crawled and indexed, make sure that all of the content (HTML markup) fully loads without the need to scroll down the page.

Lazy loading content or changes based on scroll events are things that GoogleBot can't handle. Or *at least...not very easily*

**Overall, the probability that you will experience issues with indexation is very high.**

Comment: It's worth noting that Googlebot uses a vary tall viewport (9000px was mentioned) which means it may pick up on some of your dynamically loaded content if it is added when visible.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath Totally valid. John Mueller has come out saying that he has noticed some instances where googlebot _does_ appear to scroll past static content but not very far.

Answer (score 2):

Googlebot loads pages and renders them as they appear without any user interaction. Once the page is loaded, it scans the document object model (DOM), indexes the text, and picks out links to other pages it can crawl.  Googlebot does not simulate scrolling, moving the mouse, clicking, typing, or any other action that could be taken by users.

If you want the sections of your page indexed you need to either:

- Load them all when the page first loads
- Assign each section its own URL and have links to those URLs.  You could use `pushState` to change the URL for users as they scroll down the page.

Comment: This document from Google provides more details on option 2: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly